# OpenCV Error while building on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi

When I use cmake to build opencv-3.2.0 on Raspberry Pi, I encountered a weird error at the 99% of installation.

I did not change anything to not mess anything up, however it seems like a simple code error.

Here is the error appeared in my terminal

```
/home/pi/opencv-3.2.0/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp: In function 
‘bool pyopencv_to(PyObject*, T&, const char*) [with T = 
cv::String; PyObject = _object]’:
/home/pi/opencv-3.2.0/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:730:34: error: 
invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
 char* str = PyString_AsString(obj);
In file included from /home/pi/opencv- 
3.2.0/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:1362:
```

and this is the  pyopencv_to function in cv2.cpp

```
template<>
bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, String& value, const char* name)
{
(void)name;
if(!obj || obj == Py_None)
    return true;
char* str = PyString_AsString(obj);
if(!str)
    return false;
value = String(str);
return true;
}
```

Should i manually change the code ?

Comment: Isn't OpenCV available via pacman on raspbian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in OpenCV; after I did the following change at `opencv3/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp`, it compiled for me. Change...

`char* str = PyString_AsString(obj);`

to

`const char* str = PyString_AsString(obj);`

Comment: Thanks, it's seems to only happens in the rpi from what I've found. Weird, maybe compiler version?

Comment: I don't know personally. It could be a version mismatch, but if the fix is simple enough, I just change the codebase.

Comment: Well it's a little more for me since I included this as an `ExternalProject_Add` in my CMaktLists.txt that way there are no manual installation for different system. I fixed this by creating a diff file and applying the patch with git apply. I'd still like to know why this is okay with other system though o_0. I'm suspecting just different compiler flags/version

Comment: ya probably is compiler flags